# what value for $c$ yields the estimator for $σ^2$ with the smallest mean square error among all estimators of ....

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $S'^2 = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2}{n}$ and $S^2 = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2}{n-1}$

then $S^{'2}$ is a biased estimator of $σ^2$, but $S^2$ is an unbiased estimator of the same parameter. we sample from a normal population.

$S^2$ and $S^{'2}$ are two estimators for $σ^2$ that are of the form $c\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i − \bar{Y} )^2$. What value for $c$ yields the estimator for $\sigma^2$ with the smallest mean square error among all estimators of the form $c\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i − \bar{Y} )^2$ ?

I first set $\hat{\sigma}^2 = c \sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i − \bar{Y} )^2$. The I get $E(\hat{\sigma}^2 ) = c(n-1)\sigma^2$. Then I am given $V(\hat{\sigma}^2 ) = 2c^2(n-1)\sigma^4$. I am wondering how to find $E[S^4]$ since $V(\hat{\sigma}^2 ) = E(S^4) - [E(S^2)]^2$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\bar Y)^2 \sim \sigma^2\chi^2_{n-1}.
$$

"Everybody knows" that $\mathbb E(\chi^2_k)=k$.  What is perhaps less widely known is that $\operatorname{var}(\chi^2_k)=2k$.  Where that comes from I will say something about below.

That implies
$$
\operatorname{var}\left( c\sum_{i=1}^k (Y_i-\bar Y)^2 \right) = c^2\sigma^4 2(n-1).
$$
So
\begin{align}
& \mathbb E\left(\left( \sigma^2- c\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i-\bar Y)^2 \right)^2\right) \\[10pt]
= & \sigma^4 -2\sigma^2\Big(c(n-1)\sigma^2\Big) + c^2\mathbb E((\chi^2_{n-1})^2) \\[10pt]
= & \sigma^4 -2\sigma^2\Big(c(n-1)\sigma^2\Big) + c^2 \sigma^4\Big( \operatorname{var}(\chi^2_{n-1}) + (n-1)^2  \Big). \tag 1
\end{align}

If I have the details right, the value of $c$ that makes $(1)$ as small as possible should be $1/(n+1)$ (thus an estimator with even more bias than the MLE is "best" in the mean-squared-error sense).

So where did we get $\operatorname{var}(\chi^2_k)= 2k\  {}$?

Since the chi-square random variable as distributed as $Z_1^2+\cdots+Z_k^2$ where the $Z$s are i.i.d. standard normals, the variance should be $k\operatorname{var}(Z_1^2)$.  We have
$$
\operatorname{var}(Z^2) = \mathbb E(Z^4) - \left(\mathbb E(Z^2)\right)^2 = \mathbb E(Z^4) - 1. \tag 2
$$
This is
\begin{align}
& \int_{-\infty}^\infty z^4 \varphi(z)\,dz = 2\int_0^\infty z^4 \varphi(z)\,dz \\[10pt]
= & 2\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^\infty z^4 e^{-z^2/2} \, dz = 2\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^\infty z^3 e^{-z^2/2} \Big( z \, dz \Big) \\[10pt]
= & 2\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^\infty \sqrt{2}^3 u^{3/2} e^{-u} \, du = 2\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sqrt{2}^3 \Gamma\left(\frac 5 2 \right) \\[10pt]
= & 2\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \cdot \sqrt{2}^3\cdot \frac 3 2 \cdot \frac 1 2 \Gamma\left(\frac 1 2 \right)
\end{align}

Recalling that $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$, the above reduces to $3$, so in view of $(2)$, we have $\operatorname{var}(\chi^2_1)=2$.

**A postscript prompted by comments below:** We had
$$
\sigma^4 -2\sigma^2\Big(c(n-1)\sigma^2\Big) + c^2 \sigma^4\Big( \operatorname{var}(\chi^2_{n-1}) + (n-1)^2  \Big). \tag 1
$$
Then we found that $\operatorname{var}(\chi^2_{n-1})=2(n-1)$, so $(1)$ becomes
$$
\sigma^4 -2\sigma^2\Big(c(n-1)\sigma^2\Big) + c^2 \sigma^4\Big(2(n-1) + (n-1)^2  \Big)
$$
This is $\sigma^4$ times
$$
1 -2 \Big(c(n-1) \Big) + c^2  \Big(2(n-1) + (n-1)^2  \Big).
$$
By routine algebra this becomes
$$
g(c) = (n-1)(n+1)c^2 -2(n-1)c + 1.
$$
As a function of $c$, this is a parabola that opens upward, so the lowest point is the one value of $c$ at which $g'(c)=0$.  So find
$$
g'(c) = 2(n-1)(n+1) c - 2(n-1) = 2(n-1)\Big( (n+1)c - 1 \Big).
$$
Clearly the expression in the $\Big(\text{big parentheses}\Big)$ is $0$ precisely when $c = \dfrac{1}{n+1}$.

(It can also be done by completing the square.)

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf : Correct --- I had $n+1$ where I should have had $1/(n+1)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: At this moment I suspect some details above are not quite right, but this line of reasoning should do it.

Comment: I don't know whether there's a quick way to do it that doesn't require recalling the value of $\Gamma(1/2)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Is your (1) the MSE?

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf : I hope so.

Comment: Thanks will look into details several hours from now...in the meantime, I have two posts which are related to this in terms of $E(S^4)$ and $\Gamma (\frac{1}{2})$ If you have time, feel free to give a help on it. They are the following: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737807/if-s2-frac-sum-i-1n-y-i-bary2n-and-s2-frac-sum-i-1 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737679/if-x-sqrty-1-y-2-then-find-a-multiple-of-x-that-is-an-unbiased

Comment: OK, I've fixed a detail and now I'm comfortable with this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you get your $V(\hat{\sigma}^2)$?

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf : I don't explicitly mention $\operatorname{var}(\hat\sigma^2)$.  Could you be explicit about which part you want me to elaborate on?

Comment: $$
\operatorname{var}\left( c\sum_{i=1}^k (Y_i-\bar Y)^2 \right) = c^2\sigma^4 2(n-1).
$$

Comment: We've got $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i-\bar Y)^2\sim\sigma^2\chi^2_{n-1}$, so the variance of that expression is $\sigma^4\operatorname{var}(\chi^2_{n-1})$.  And $\operatorname{var}(\chi^2_{n-1})=2(n-1)$.  The reason why the variance of the chi-square distribution is twice the number of degrees of freedom is explained in the part where I find the integral whose value is $\mathbb E(Z^4)$.  ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Can you elaborate how you got $\frac{1}{n+1}$ as I keep getting the wrong number? If you could elaborate how you got var$(\chi_{n-1}^2) = 2(n-1)$ will be great

Comment: The way I got $\operatorname{var}(\chi_{n-1}^2)$ is at the end above.  I showed that $\operatorname{var}(\chi^2_1)=2$.  Since the chi-square distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom is the distribution of the sum of $n$ independent random variables, each with a chi-square distribution with $1$ degree of freedom, that does it.  The variance is $\operatorname{var}(\chi^2_1)=\mathbb E((\chi^2_1)^2)- (\mathbb E(\chi^2_1))^2$.  Since $\mathbb E(\chi^2_1)=1$, it remains only to show that $\mathbb E((\chi^2_1)^2)=3$.  That's the integral at the end.

Comment: Could you show how you got $\frac{1}{n+1}$?

Comment: Why you showed var$(\chi_1^2)$ instead of var$(\chi_{n-1}^2)$?

Comment: Because $\chi^2_k$ is the distribution of the sum of $k$ independent random variables each with a $\chi^2_1$ distribution, so you can find the variance of $\chi^2_1$ and then just multiply it by $k$ to get the variance of $\chi^2_k$.

Comment: I've added a postscript on how $c=1/(n+1)$ was found.